# ant perforce - set ant property with perforce version number

Tags: ant, perforce

I need to interrogate a file under perforce control from ant and do stuff with that perforce meta data(labels/tags, latest revision number,...).

```
<target name="doSomethingWithP4MetaData">
      ????

     <echo>${aP4File.lastId} </echo>
     <echo>${aP4File.description}</echo>
</target>
```

Problem is that p4stat examples does not look like it does what I want to do.

Any suggestions?
Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to take a look at the Ant integration we built a couple years ago, P4Ant. Here are the docs on its fstat method:

http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4ant/p4tasks.html#p4jfstat

You can grab the tool [from our website.](http://www.perforce.com/downloads/Perforce-Software-Version-Management/complete_list/Customer?qt-perforce_downloads_step_3=3#qt-perforce_downloads_step_3)

edit: extending the answer a bit so I can have proper formatting to address your comment:

You want P4JChanges then: http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4ant/p4tasks.html#p4jchanges

With it you can do:

```
<p4jchanges
    maxmostrecent="1"
    files="..."
/>
```

the list of changelist numbers will be put in the 'p4.changelists' property.

Comment: google is not showing any example of how to use p4fstat. can anyone pont me at an example???

Comment: What in particular are you trying to with the information from fstat? I might be able to craft an example with more details.

Comment: I have checked out/pulled a branch into my local computer for development. In a sub directory of that branch I need to know the latest change comment for all files under that point "p4  changes -m 1 -s submitted" looks closest to what I want. CD into sub directory. If I specify no file then I get last change submitted to depot, not where I have cd-ed to. But I want last change from where I am.  If I can get p4ant to wrap that up in a ant parameter, that would be perfect.  I need to supply that as an argument to another command line executable.